# Is Email Verification on Mobile App Sign up a bad UX?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, email, signup-signon

We have a user sign up form in our product. In web version we have a email verification process. We will send a verification mail with an activation link after sign up.

Now we have a mobile app for the same product.I feel like following the same process is not good on a mobile because it makes the sign up process longer and user needs to use his mail client and browser to complete sign up process.

A "loooong" process in mobile is really bad, How can we solve this issue.

Comment: You'll find your solution here - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23103/sign-up-double-opt-in-still-best-practice-what-about-mobile